# Blender Video Editing, Newbie, channel 0

Tags: edit-mode, video

Sorry, a very newbie question.

I'm trying to make a simple video with Blender, but I'm a bit confused about the Sequencer and what I think is channel 0.

After I drag in my video (about 3 mins), it will only play back in a loop on channel 0. This has an underlined dark red background. But though my video is longer than this, Blender appears to be in a loop (as defined by channel 0) for the first 10 seconds.

My workflow is simple, start blender, new video editing project, select video file and drag it into sequencer.

Then however long my video is, blender only plays back the first 10s in a loop which appears to be defined by an *uneditable* channel 0.

Whats going on? I know I'm missing something simple, but what is it?

Thanks

Comment: Just set the correct start and end frame in a [timeline area](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html#frame-range) or the [*Properties Area, Scene > Render > Output > Dimensions*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/settings.html#dimensions-panel). The default frame range 1-250 is 10s at 25 fps, so you will have to increase it 3min * 60s * 25fps = 4500

Comment: Channel zero is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

I'm not sure of some of the "blender language" yet, but my problem was because I dropped a video in and then pressed space (as play).

At the top right pane of the screen is a panel that is described as "Scene" and has a drop down panel that is titled (?) Dimensions. I think this is what Leander described, but there appears to be nothing described as a "Properties Area". (What should I read to understand this?)

My problem was fixed by changing the "frame start" and "frame end" in said Dimensions drop-down panel to be something appropriate for the video I had dragged in.

I had referred to this as a channel 0 being the sort-of-blank channel underneath channel 1. I'm not yet sure of its proper name. But I see now that the "frame start", "frame end" combo selects a display area in the background of the channels, and that the area I refer to is in the foreground, and contains the text for markers and perhaps other things...

Thanks very much for the pointers, I'm hopefully on my way now.